# Parsing Apns payload

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

Need to parse Apns payload and get the url for deep linking.

I tried to parse the apns pay load. It gives me a dictionary with key aps & has multiple key values for the deep link url. One for each letter of the url.

```
func getPushNotificationDeeplink(notificationDictionary: [AnyHashable:Any]) {
        print("Notification dictionary = \(notificationDictionary)")

        guard let aps = notificationDictionary["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject] else {

            return
        }

    }
```

Result:

```
Notification dictionary = [AnyHashable("12"): e, AnyHashable("28"): s, AnyHashable("38"): l, AnyHashable("27"): n, AnyHashable("aps"): {
        alert =     {
            body = "Message 12";
            title = "Notification R2";
        };
        badge = 1;
    }, AnyHashable("18"): a, AnyHashable("40"): }, AnyHashable("29"): f, AnyHashable("10"): m, AnyHashable("1"): ", AnyHashable("13"): -, AnyHashable("37"): i, AnyHashable("32"): -, AnyHashable("0"): {, AnyHashable("3"): r, AnyHashable("23"): /, AnyHashable("15"): o, AnyHashable("24"): t, AnyHashable("20"): d, AnyHashable("5"): ", AnyHashable("34"): e, AnyHashable("36"): a, AnyHashable("19"): r, AnyHashable("39"): ", AnyHashable("2"): u, AnyHashable("31"): r, AnyHashable("7"): ", AnyHashable("33"): d, AnyHashable("16"): r, AnyHashable("21"): :, AnyHashable("30"): e, AnyHashable("17"): w, AnyHashable("35"): t, AnyHashable("11"): m, AnyHashable("22"): /, AnyHashable("25"): r, AnyHashable("9"): i, AnyHashable("4"): l, AnyHashable("26"): a, AnyHashable("8"): a, AnyHashable("6"): :, AnyHashable("14"): f]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
func getPushNotificationDeeplink(notificationDictionary: [AnyHashable:Any]) {
        print("Notification dictionary = \(notificationDictionary)")

        guard let aps = notificationDictionary["aps"] as? [String: Any] , 
              let alert = aps["alert"] as? [String: Any] , 
              let body = alert["body"] as? String , 
              let title = alert["title"] as? String else  {

            return
        }

       print("Body is \(body) Title is \(title)")

}
```